# How to obtain a suitable model with external regressors in auto.arima

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, modeling, forecasting

I am trying to fit, in order to use it as a baseline for comparison, an ARIMA model with external regressors. I would like to insert dummy variables to take into account daily seasonality. The reason for that can be understood from the picture of the data presented below. Indeed, during night time, the values are zero and I would like this behavior to be taken into account in the model.

[image: Beginning of the time series]

The data set can be downloaded here : [dataset_OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag7cZzrbsD0ChxfJ4yJ-SRSNK1Ci)

So far I tried to use the auto.arima function from the forecast package in R, as shown by the following snippet of code :

```
Y <- ts(data = Data_Exemple$value, frequency = 24)
hour_y <- hour(Data_Exemple$Date)
xreg_hour <- model.matrix((~as.factor(hour_y)))
colnames(xreg_hour) <- seq(1,24)
```

Which gives an external regressor like this :

```
##   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
## 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
## 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
## 3 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
## 4 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
## 5 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
## 6 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Then I try to fit the model :

```
fit <- auto.arima(y = Y, D=1, d=0,seasonal = TRUE, trace = TRUE, xreg = xreg_hour)
```

Howewer it fails to find a suitable model :

```
 Fitting models using approximations to speed things up...

 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,0)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,0)(1,1,0)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,0,1)(0,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,0)[24]                    : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(0,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(2,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,1,0)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,1,2)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(0,1,0)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(2,1,2)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,2)(1,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(3,0,2)(1,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,1)(1,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,3)(1,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(1,0,1)(1,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(3,0,3)(1,1,1)[24] with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,0,2)(1,1,1)[24]                    : Inf
 Show Traceback
Error in auto.arima(y = Y, D = 1, d = 0, seasonal = TRUE, trace = TRUE, : No suitable ARIMA model found
```

My question is : am I doing something clearly wrong in my use of external regressors ? I thought that the number of dummy variables could have been the problem but using a night / day couple of dummy variables doesn't help.

If someone have some hindsights, I would be glad to know about it ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I very much appreciate the attempt to create a fully reproducible example. Good work! You only did 1 thing slightly wrong - they strongly prefer you to use built-in or artificial data rather than external links to your file, due to malware being spread over Stack Overflow that way. That rule includes Google Drive, OneDrive, and DropBox. The one you used is less well known so it's even higher risk...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this mistake, it is now (hopefully) solved and hosted on OneDrive.

Comment: Could it be a problem due to the fact that the first column of `xreg_hour` is all 1?

Comment: If I understood properly, it is necessary to add this intercept in order to have a possible solution for the regression problem but I'm not sure of that aspect !

Comment: Maybe it's a multicollinearity problem, have you tried with removing the last column? Your dummies should always be N - 1, if N is the periodicity (24-1 in your case)

Comment: Riccardo, do my dummies have to be exatcly N-1 or can it be less ? Because I tried with a night / day couple of dummies and I obtain the same error...

Comment: If N = 24 then yes they have to be N-1, if you use night/day with only 2 dummies then try with 2-1. I suppose it's the safest choice.